# Spring Framework - Display Warning Message as opposed to Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have Use Cases that require the User to be show a Warning message as opposed to an Error message.  The user will be shown once and then they can proceed.  My problem is since it's not a Validation error the flow goes thru and the operation is performed without displaying the message. Therefore the user performs an action, he is warned once and then let thru.

Am I missing something? I looked around but there doesn't seem to be the concept of a warning message in Spring. Thanks for your help or suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you clarify what you're trying to achieve, and provide some code samples.

Answer (score 0):

In my ignorance of Spring and Spring-MVC, I created a `Messages` class that contains lists of errors and messages.  I store an object of this type in the request scope and reference it in my JSP somewhat like this:

```
<c:if test="${Messages.hasMessages}">
    <c:forEach items="${Messages.messages}" var="message">
        ${message}<br/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${Messages.hasErrors}">
    <c:forEach items="${Messages.errors}" var="error">
        ${error}<br/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

In my actual JSP, I style it as needed and generally dump messages and errors in a `<ul>` list.

Comment: I also face the same issue. Currently my application does validation using Spring Validation but I need to show warning and errors in the validation process but Spring currently supports only errors. Could you or anyone guide of how to render warnings as opposed to Errors in Spring